# Splitting a csv column from select query into multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure

```
SELECT [ShipWorks].[dbo].[OrderItem].[Code] AS Code, 
    CASE WHEN (LEN(ISNULL(MAX([ShipWorks].[dbo].[OrderItem].[Location]),'')) = 1)
            THEN MAX([ShipWorks].[dbo].[OrderItem].[Location]) 
         ELSE MAX([Picklist].[dbo].[ItemData].[InventoryLocation])
    END AS Location, 
SUM([ShipWorks].[dbo].[OrderItem].[Quantity]) AS Quantity, 
MAX(LEFT([ShipWorks].[dbo].[Store].[StoreName], 1)) AS Store
FROM [ShipWorks].[dbo].[OrderItem] 
INNER JOIN [ShipWorks].[dbo].[Order] ON [ShipWorks].[dbo].[OrderItem].[OrderID] = [ShipWorks].[dbo].[Order].[OrderID] 
INNER JOIN [ShipWorks].[dbo].[Store] ON [ShipWorks].[dbo].[Order].[StoreID] = [ShipWorks].[dbo].[Store].[StoreID] 
LEFT JOIN [ShipWorks].[dbo].[AmazonOrder] ON [ShipWorks].[dbo].[AmazonOrder].[OrderID] = [ShipWorks].[dbo].[Order].[OrderID]
LEFT JOIN [Picklist].[dbo].[ItemData] ON [Picklist].[dbo].[ItemData].[InventoryNumber] = [ShipWorks].[dbo].[OrderItem].[Code] OR
          [Picklist].[dbo].[ItemData].[MediaCreator] = [OrderItem].[Code]
WHERE [ShipWorks].[dbo] [Order].[LocalStatus] = 'Recently Downloaded' AND ([ShipWorks].[dbo].[AmazonOrder].[FulfillmentChannel] = 2 OR [ShipWorks].[dbo].[Store].[StoreName] <> 'Amazon')
GROUP BY [ShipWorks].[dbo].[OrderItem].[Code]
ORDER BY Location
```

that returns this:

```
Code              Location                                  Quantity    Store
L698-W-EA          NULL                                      2           A
L82009-EA          A1K2, A1N2, C4Y3, CBP2                    2           A
L80401-A-EA        A1S2, SHIP, R2F1, CBP5, BRP, BRP1-20      17          A
CWD2132W-BOX-25PK  A-AISLE                                   1           M
GM22660003-EA      B1K2                                      1           M
```

I want to split the Location column into multiple columns .

```
Code               loc1  loc2  loc3  loc4  loc5 loc6        Quantity    Store
L698-W-EA          NULL                                      2           A
L82009-EA          A1K2, A1N2, C4Y3, CBP2                    2           A
L80401-A-EA        A1S2, SHIP, R2F1, CBP5, BRP, BRP1-20      17          A
CWD2132W-BOX-25PK  A-AI                                      1           M
GM22660003-EA      B1K2                                      1           M
```

I found this answer but that was for [postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns). Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns), but it returns a table with multiple rows and you can select the top 1 but I want all the results and I'm not sure how to use the tvf Split(string, ',')in the stored procedure to get the result set I want?

This select statement results in a error: 
*'Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.'*

```
SELECT [ShipWorks].[dbo].[OrderItem].[Code] AS Code, 
    CASE WHEN (LEN(ISNULL(MAX([ShipWorks].[dbo].[OrderItem].[Location]),'')) = 1)
            THEN MAX((SELECT TOP 1 i.* FROM dbo.Split([ShipWorks].[dbo].[OrderItem].[Location], ',') as i)) 
         ELSE MAX((SELECT TOP 1 i.* FROM dbo.Split([ShipWorks].[dbo].[OrderItem].[Location], ',') as i))
    END AS Location, 
SUM([ShipWorks].[dbo].[OrderItem].[Quantity]) AS Quantity, 
MAX(LEFT([ShipWorks].[dbo].[Store].[StoreName], 1)) AS Store
FROM [ShipWorks].[dbo].[OrderItem] 
INNER JOIN [ShipWorks].[dbo].[Order] ON [ShipWorks].[dbo].[OrderItem].[OrderID] = [ShipWorks].[dbo].[Order].[OrderID] 
INNER JOIN [ShipWorks].[dbo].[Store] ON [ShipWorks].[dbo].[Order].[StoreID] = [ShipWorks].[dbo].[Store].[StoreID] 
LEFT JOIN [ShipWorks].[dbo].[AmazonOrder] ON [ShipWorks].[dbo].[AmazonOrder].[OrderID] = [ShipWorks].[dbo].[Order].[OrderID]
LEFT JOIN [Picklist].[dbo].[ItemData] ON [Picklist].[dbo].[ItemData].[InventoryNumber] = [ShipWorks].[dbo].[OrderItem].[Code] OR
          [Picklist].[dbo].[ItemData].[MediaCreator] = [OrderItem].[Code]
WHERE [Order].[LocalStatus] = 'Recently Downloaded' AND ([ShipWorks].[dbo].[AmazonOrder].[FulfillmentChannel] = 2 OR [ShipWorks].[dbo].[Store].[StoreName] <> 'Amazon')
GROUP BY [ShipWorks].[dbo].[OrderItem].[Code]
ORDER BY Location
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Making use of Jeff Moden's Tally-Ho! CSV splitter from [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
WITH E1(N) AS (
           SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
           SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
           SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
       ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
            SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() 
                                                        OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
        ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just
                     -- once for each delimiter)
            SELECT 1 UNION ALL
            SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
        ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
            SELECT s.N1,
                   ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
            FROM cteStart s
        )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final
     -- element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
go
```

We can code the solution as an apply against Jeff's function and a pivot like so:

```
with data as (
    select Code,Location,Quantity,Store from ( values
        ('L698-W-EA',          NULL,                                      2, 'A')
       ,('L82009-EA',          'A1K2, A1N2, C4Y3, CBP2',                  2, 'A')
       ,('L80401-A-EA',        'A1S2, SHIP, R2F1, CBP5, BRP, BRP1-20',    17,'A')
       ,('CWD2132W-BOX-25PK',  'A-AISLE',                                 1, 'M')
       ,('GM22660003-EA',      'B1K2',                                    1, 'M')
    )data(Code,Location,Quantity,Store)
)
,shredded as (
    select Code,Location,Quantity,Store,t.*
    from data
    cross apply [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](data.Location,',') as t
)
select 
    pvt.Code,pvt.Quantity,pvt.Store
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[1],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc1
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[2],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc2
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[3],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc3
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[4],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc4
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[5],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc5 
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[6],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc6
from shredded
pivot (max(Item) for ItemNumber in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])) pvt;
;
go
```

yielding this:

```
Code              Quantity    Store Loc1     Loc2     Loc3     Loc4     Loc5     Loc6
----------------- ----------- ----- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------
L698-W-EA         2           A                                                   
L82009-EA         2           A     A1K2      A1N2     C4Y3     CBP2              
L80401-A-EA       17          A     A1S2      SHIP     R2F1     CBP5     BRP      BRP1-20
CWD2132W-BOX-25PK 1           M     A-AISLE                                       
GM22660003-EA     1           M     B1K2
```